# Incorrect sum behavior over a range

Tags: summation

What is going on here?

```
f[1] = 0;
f[n_] := Module[{d},
   If [Mod[n, 7] == 0, f[n/7], d = Length@IntegerDigits[n, 7]; 
                               Total@IntegerDigits[7^d - n, 7]]];

{Sum[f[i], {i, Range@1000000}], Sum[f[i], {i, 1, 1000000}]}
(* {21646932, 21646932} *)

{Sum[f[i], {i, Range@1000001}], Sum[f[i], {i, 1, 1000001}]}
(* {21646964, 21646970} *)
```

Note the different results in the second set of sums (the first is the correct one). 13.3.1 on MacOS.

NB: This is similar to another question I asked today, now deleted, that was apparently not reproducible.

Comment: Is the boundary always at 1000000<-->1000001 when you get incorrect results?

Comment: Yes, it is. Values below 1000000 seem to do the right thing, while values above that do not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replicate your results

```
$Version
(* "13.3.1 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)
```

It looks like Mathematica attempts some invalid algebraic manipulation.  If I force numerical evaluation, I get consistent results

```
g[1] = 0;
g[n_?NumericQ] := 
  Module[{d}, 
   If[Mod[n, 7] == 0, g[n/7], d = Length@IntegerDigits[n, 7];
    Total@IntegerDigits[7^d - n, 7]]];

{Sum[g[i], {i, Range@1000000}], Sum[g[i], {i, 1, 1000000}]}
(* {21646932, 21646932} *)

{Sum[g[i], {i, Range@1000001}], Sum[g[i], {i, 1, 1000001}]}
(* {21646964, 21646964} *)
```

Comment: Just confirming replication of the original problem and the solution of @mikado works on Windows 13.3.1 as well.

Comment: Okay, this is strange, but I'm still not able to reproduce these results. On `13.3.1 for Mac OS X` I get `{21646932, 21646932}` for the first example and `{21646964, 21646964}` for the second example. I don't know what the right answers are--just reporting that I get different results.

Answer (score 6):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

f[1] = 0;
f[n_] :=
  Module[{d}, If[Mod[n, 7] == 0, f[n/7],
    d = Length@IntegerDigits[n, 7];
    Total@IntegerDigits[7^d - n, 7]]];
```

The possible issues section of the documentation for [`Sum`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sum.html) points out that symbolic evaluation is used above the threshold value of 10^6. The stated means of forcing procedural summation is to use the option `Method -> "Procedural"`

```
{Sum[f[i], {i, Range@1000001}, Method -> "Procedural"],
  Sum[f[i], {i, 1, 1000001}, Method -> "Procedural"]} //
 AbsoluteTiming

(* {6.9459, {21646964, 21646964}} *)
```

Note the timing difference when using [`memoization`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/WriteAFunctionThatRemembersComputedValues.html)

```
Clear[f]

f[1] = 0;
f[n_] := f[n] =
   Module[{d}, If[Mod[n, 7] == 0, f[n/7],
     d = Length@IntegerDigits[n, 7];
     Total@IntegerDigits[7^d - n, 7]]];

{Sum[f[i], {i, Range@1000001}, Method -> "Procedural"],
  Sum[f[i], {i, 1, 1000001}, Method -> "Procedural"]} //
 AbsoluteTiming

(* {4.11074, {21646964, 21646964}} *)
```